# Can I get feedback on my dissertation from my lecturer before handing it in?

Tags: thesis, united-kingdom, feedback

I'll be honest here I'm *terrified* by the idea of my final major project. I was wondering if it's acceptable or common practice to get feedback from my supervisor (lecturer) on my dissertation prior to submitting as I go along?

I'm from the U.K. if that helps.

Comment: Who will be grading the project?

Comment: Confused. What are you talking about? A dissertation is usually a major project to get a degree which your advisor should be involved in heavily.

Comment: @Azor Could be a final project for a master in the UK, something like a journal-club type paper.

Comment: @user What do you mean? IME "journal club" means people meet and discuss articles of interest. No theses or dissertations

Comment: Depends on the uni and institution. But generally, a lecturer will give general feedback, sometimes even detailed, on your work. How else would one learn? Why don't you ask them?

Comment: The answer to this will vary not only between universities and departments, but often between individual advisors within the same department.  Best thing is to ask your advisor.

Comment: @Azor Guess I don't know much about clubs. What I meant was some kind of essay on a paper, a set of papers, or a topic.

Answer (score 1):

Students at any level working on big projects learn best and produce better work when they confer frequently with advisors (and fellow students). Sharing drafts is crucial. It's how you reduce the terror you feel. Submitting a final product when you've seen no feedback courts disaster.

That said, I've no idea whether your advisor or institution allows, requires or forbids this in your particular case.